# columnize loop output in python

Tags: python, loops, output, multiple-columns

I have a code in python like so:

```
def sth(mlist):
    for line in mlist:
        out = func(param1, param2)
        if out:
            print " [+] %-15s %20s " % (line, out.rjust(30, '.'))
        else:
            a = 'Not Covered!!'
            print " [-] %-15s %20s " % (target, a.rjust(30, '.'))
```

and I get the nasty output when running the code:

```
 [-] http://a.com .................Not Covered!! 
 [-] http://abcd.info .................Not Covered!! 
 [+] http://abcdef.net ....................something  
 [-] https://c.com .................Not Covered!! 
 [+] https://efghij.org .................other thing
.
.
.
```

How can I have the best form of output for such threads, for example something like:

```
 [-] http://a.com ......................... Not Covered!! 
 [-] http://abcd.info ..................... Not Covered!! 
 [+] http://abcdef.net .................... something  
 [-] https://c.com ........................ Not Covered!! 
 [+] https://efghij.org ................... other thing
.
.
.
```

## Note:

Even other solutions rather than using `ljust` are welcome too.

Comment: Replace `%20s` with `%30s` so it matches with `rjust`.

Comment: @feliks No, This list may be contained by other websites.

Comment: @feliks, I updated the outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you are open to solutions that do not use `rjust` or `ljust`, you could decide how many `.` you want to print and subtract the `len` of the `line` from that.

Short example:

```
print(' [+] {0} {1} {2}'.format(line, '.' * (50 - len(line)), out))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-compute the longest URL and *left*-justify that entry with dots, so that it pairs up more nicely:

```
>>> signs = ['-', '+', '-']  
... URLs = ['http://foobar.com', 'http://much_longer_foo.com', 'http://medium_foo.com']  
... tails = ['Longer shouting ending!!', 'different ending', 'Longer shouting ending!!'] 
...   
... maxlen = max(map(len, URLs))  
... linefmt = " [{{sign}}] {{URL:.<{maxlen}}}{{tail:.>30}}".format(maxlen=maxlen)  
... for sign,URL,tail in zip(signs, URLs, tails):  
...     print(linefmt.format(sign=sign, URL=URL, tail=tail)) 
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 [-] http://foobar.com...............Longer shouting ending!!
 [+] http://much_longer_foo.com..............different ending
 [-] http://medium_foo.com...........Longer shouting ending!!
```

As you can see, I changed to the use of `.format` rather than percent formatting. This is mostly a question of preference.

What's important is that we first build the format string with the length of the longest URL, and then use the resulting format string. The result is slightly different from what you expect: there's no whitespace surrounding the dots. You can add those manually if you insist on having them.

Note that in python 3.6 and up you could use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to do this more elegantly:

```
>>> signs = ['-', '+', '-']  
... URLs = ['http://foobar.com', 'http://much_longer_foo.com', 'http://medium_foo.com']  
... tails = ['Longer shouting ending!!', 'different ending', 'Longer shouting ending!!'] 
...   
... maxlen = max(map(len, URLs))  
... for sign,URL,tail in zip(signs, URLs, tails):  
...     print(f' [{sign}] {URL:.<{maxlen}}{tail:.>30}')  
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 [-] http://foobar.com...............Longer shouting ending!!
 [+] http://much_longer_foo.com..............different ending
 [-] http://medium_foo.com...........Longer shouting ending!!
```

Also, as you can see, I'd suggest using a single format string and passing it the sign/URL/ending separately. This will help you reduce code repetition and ease maintainability.